# $x^2+y^2 = n$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

For every prime p and integer n , $x^2+y^2 = n$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ .
I think I need some number theory result to prove this. Can I get any help with this?

Comment: More than half of the elements of ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$ are squares, so at least one of the set $\{n-y^2 : y \in {\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}\}$ must be a square.

Comment: Got it . Thank you